# What should be action to make the log clean without re creating prod branch in git?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch

While working in Git, we have decided to take some critical fix in prod branch. Now unfortunately some unwanted changes **C1** are merged. Now we can revert the commits but it will increase the one more log which management does not want. management wants clean list of critical commits only. Now one way is to delete full prod branch and then create new prod branch again and take only critical commits, but in that case prod branch creation history will be lost which is not accepted to management.

**What should be action to make the log clean without re creating prod branch in git?**

Comment: did you check "git rebase -i  " ? (test it on specific branch :) )

Comment: @LeGEC commits are already merged. Two commits are merged. But i need one commit only.

Comment: Use `git rebase -i <sha1 before merge>`, and delete the commits you don't want to keep

Comment: @LeGEC could you please explain with example in answer? Thanks